# react-native-safe-area-context not working?

Tags: react-native

I'm using an Android simulator and the SafeAreaProvider is not working (i.e. going to far too the top of the screen)

```
import { StatusBar } from "expo-status-bar";
import { NavigationContainer } from "@react-navigation/native";
import RootNavigator from "./navigator/RootNavigator";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { store } from "./redux/store";
import { SafeAreaProvider } from "react-native-safe-area-context";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <SafeAreaProvider>
      <NavigationContainer>
        <StatusBar style="auto" />
        <Provider store={store}>
          <RootNavigator />
        </Provider>
      </NavigationContainer>
    </SafeAreaProvider>
  );
}
```

Comment: Are you wrapping your screen in a SafeAreaView or using useSafeAreaInsets?

Comment: Just using above  "  <SafeAreaProvider> </SafeAreaProvider>"

Comment: check the docs https://github.com/th3rdwave/react-native-safe-area-context you have to wrap your component in the safe area view or use the insets in your styles

Answer (score 4):

You need to wrap your application with SafeAreaView to make it work. Import it from the same library and update your code to this:

```
<SafeAreaProvider>
 <SafeAreaView>
  <NavigationContainer>
   <StatusBar style="auto" />
    <Provider store={store}>
     <RootNavigator />
    </Provider>
  </NavigationContainer>
 </SafeAreaView>
</SafeAreaProvider>
```